# Mongoose Model methods do not work in Nodejs app.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, model

I created a database using mongoose and had mongodb server connected also mongodb shell running in Hyper terminal.

My VScode App.js as below:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitDB');
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type:String,
    required:[true,"No name specified."]
  },
  rating:{
    type:Number,
    min:1,
    max:10
  },
  review:String
});
const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit",fruitSchema);
const fruit = new Fruit ({
  name: "Apple",
  rating:4,
  review:"Pretty good as a fruit."
})
 fruit.save();
```

Then I ran node app.js. I checked the collection in mongosh. It shows correctly as one document added in the database collection.

Then I wrote a Model method in app.js to update the document as below:
`Fruit.updateOne({name:"Apple"},{review:"Nice apple")`

Then run node app.js and I checked in mongosh. The document is no change.

I tried to delete this document using Model method in app.js.
`Fruit.deleteOne({name:"Apple"})`
It does not work either.

I use mongosh to udpate and delete the document, it works fine.
I have no idea why Model method does not work in app.js.
could anyone help?